# "Were I you I would reward you/myself a little"

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctives

> Were I you I would reward you a little.

Is this sentence correct or should we use

> Were I you I would reward myself a little.

I can't give you context as it was asked in my exam.

Comment: You asked the exact same question on [ELU SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361316/how-to-use-subjunctive-mood).

Comment: A native speaker would most likely use the reflexive pronoun *myself* there.

Comment: The reflexive "myself" is correct. Btw, this isn't really the subjunctive. Subjunctive is not a mood, but a clause construction headed by a plain (infinitival) form verb, as in "It is essential that he **be** told immediately". The "were" in your example is best called "irrealis", a unique mood form limited to "were"; essentially an untidy relic of an earlier system.

Comment: I'm not sure I have _ever_ heard anybody say _were I you_. The slightly less literary equivalent _If I were you_ is however very common.

Answer (score 1):

What the writer intends to say is almost certainly:

> Were I you I would reward myself a little.

The other sentence:

> Were I you I would reward you a little.

seems to be suggesting that the speaker wants to be rewarded, but it's ambiguous.  If that's what's intended, the following would be clearer:

> Were I you and you were me, I would reward you a little.

(I invite anyone who is bothered by the "me" in the above sentence to read [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103502/if-i-were-you-and-you-were-i) very interesting discussion.)